# How to associate a feature with a customer request

Tags: azure-devops

Our product manager want to be able to associate a feature to a customer request/requirement. I am trying to find a way to do it without customizing the WIT fields. I don't want to hard bind a feature to a customer and still allow the product management reporting capabilities based on a customer name or aggregate on it. Any ideas? BTW tags are not an option.

Comment: Not sure how did you want to associate them. Assume you are using the CMMI process template, just create a `Requirement` work item, then link the requirement work item to a `Feature`.

Comment: We are using Agile. I am just looking to see if there is another kind of WIT or external tool / extension that can be used.

Comment: You can create a new work item type to track the customer request, then associate the work items to feature.

Comment: Thank you, I skipped the option for new WIT type.

Comment: Well, the simplest way is creating a text file (or word, excel, etc you like) and writing the customer requests in the file, then attach the file to the feature work item.